# spread array of values to parameters in function call

Tags: python

I am getting an array of values and I want to send them to a predefined function with the same parameter count.

The naive way is to do:

```
 values = [1,2,3,4] # getting it from outside
 if len(values) == 1:
     func(values[0])
 elif len(values) == 2:
     func(values[0], values[1])
 .
 .
 .
```

is there more elegant way ?

Comment: `func(values)` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [arbitrary argument lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists)

```
def func(*args):

    for arg in args:
        print(arg)

values = [1]
func(*values)
values = [1, 2]
func(*values)

func(1)
func(1,2)
```

The output will be

```
1
1
2
```

Or just pass the entire array to the function via `func(values)`

```
def func(values):

    for value in values:
        print(value)

values = [1]
func(values)

values = [1, 2]
func(values)
```

Comment: Not necessarily when you can do just `func(values)`.

Comment: My problem is that the function can be: def func(a): or def func(a,b): etc so I I call func I won't have to do the if else over the array size, but just call func with the array and it will know how to put array[0] in a var and array[1] in b var automatically

Comment: So you have variable arguments, `func(a)` till `func(a,b,c,d)` ? well you would need some kind of conditional to identify how many arguments are being passed, or you would need an intermediate functions which can do that for you @asaf You can't really avoid this where number of arguments are variable